# what is the macro "section"?

Tags: elisp-macros

Exploring far-out init files, I found this [here](https://github.com/ChrisBlom/emacs.d/blob/master/init.el):

```
(defmacro section (name &rest a) `(progn ,@a))
(put 'section 'lisp-indent-function 'defun)
```

then it's used AFAICT as a sort of wrapper, not sure of the genius behind all this. Thought it would be a good thing to know. Can someone explain what it all means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It enables you to write code like this:

```
(section testing
  (setq a 1)
  (setq b 2))

(section configuration
  (evil-mode)
  (helm-mode))
```

This code expands to the following:

```
(progn
 (setq a 1)
 (setq b 2))

(progn
 (evil-mode)
 (helm-mode))
```

Normal people would write it like this:

```
;;; testing
(setq a 1)
(setq b 2)

;;; configuration
(evil-mode)
(helm-mode)
```

All in all, it's a cute trick.  You can find out the above by using the macrostep package and seeing the expansion yourself.

Comment: So it adds the idiom of saying "stuff inside this 'section' will be run together because it's all related stuff." Nice. Can't do this so deftly out in Blub-land.

Comment: Due to `progn`, the `section` form also returns the value of the final form which was evaluated.